# Batch script - Issue to use conditional statements

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script which needs to check for computer IP address range and a text file under user profile, if both are met then it has to go to end otherwise calls a batch file then continue to check for another IP range and text file and so on..

> IP ranges and text file are as follow:
>
> IP 10.0.50.xxx, 10.0.51.xxx:
> search for %username%10.txt
>
> IP 10.0.1.xxx, 10.0.5.xxx: search for
> %username%11.txt
>
> IP 10.0.60.xxx: search for %username%12.txt
>
> IP
> 10.0.100.xxx: search for %username%13.txt

I tried multiple variation of if else and && || statements without luck. The scripts only checks for the text file but not the IP range.

I removed the else , if statements and only pasted the code I'm using. Can anyone please have a look and let me know the best method to implement else, if into this code? Thank you

```
  for %%a in (50,51) do if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\%username%10.txt" (  IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.%%a.">Nul 2>&1 && call sydprintmap.bat   
)
  for %%a in (1,5) do if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\%username%11.txt" (   IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.%%a.">Nul 2>&1 && call melprintmap.bat 
)
  for %%a in (60) do if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\%username%12.txt" (   IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.%%a.">Nul 2>&1 && call wynprintmap.bat  
)
  for %%a in (100) do if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\%username%13.txt" (   IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.%%a.">Nul 2>&1 && call adlprintmap.bat
)
```

PS:
What I need is:

1: if IP address is within range and the text file exists then go to end.

2- If IP address is within range but the text file doesn't exist then run the specific script.

3- if IP address is not within range then go to next line (without checking for relevant text file)

Comment: `if NOT exist` to check, if a file exists? Rethink... (I'd use `ipconfig |findstr /irc:"IPv4.*: 10.0.5[01]." && if exist %username%10.txt ...`

Comment: (note: in german windows, `ipconfig` says `IPv4-Adresse...`, so I dropped the space after `IPv4`)

Comment: We need to make sure both conditions are met before calling for a script. else it can go to next line. If the text file exists under user profile it means the settings are applied correctly.

Comment: "How can I isolate 1 from 100 ?" `findstr` uses `.` as a wildcard ("any char"). To explicitely search for a dot, escape it: `FindStr/IRC:"IPv4.*: 10\.0\.%%a\."`

Comment: `&&` executes the `if exist...` command only, if `findstr` is successful (the IP is in the range).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the task, but you may try this:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=:" %%A In ('IPConfig^|FindStr/IRC:"\<IPv4.*\ :\ 10\.0\.[156]\."'
) Do For /F "Tokens=3 Delims=." %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "byte3=%%A"

If "%byte3%" GEq "50" If "%byte3%" LEq "51" If Not Exist "%UserProfile%\%UserName%10.txt" sydprintmap.bat
If "%byte3%" Equ "1" If Not Exist "%UserProfile%\%UserName%11.txt" melprintmap.bat
If "%byte3%" Equ "5" If Not Exist "%UserProfile%\%UserName%11.txt" melprintmap.bat
If "%byte3%" Equ "60" If Not Exist "%UserProfile%\%UserName%12.txt" wynprintmap.bat
If "%byte3%" Equ "100" If Not Exist "%UserProfile%\%UserName%13.txt" adlprintmap.bat
```